# Login issue into Microsoft azure account

Tags: azure

I have a v-xxxxx.microsoft.com ID through which i have created a account in microsoft Azure  90 days free trial account. 

I am not able to login microsoft axure portal through v-xxxxx.microsoft.com ID. It is showing me error as "Sorry, we can't sign you in here with your @MICROSOFT.COM account."

Please can someone help here ?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use some other id to create the free trial...
BTW Are you working at microsoft?

Comment: I have created the trial account already...So could there is a way to use the existing account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things you can try as below:

1. Use In-Private Browsing with IE9/10 and see if you can enter your credentials
2. With #1 try to use the URL redirecting to domain ID 
   https://manage.windowsazure.com/?whr=microsoft.com
3. If you have other live account already included as co-admin or service administrator with your Azure Subscription please use that live account instead.

Finally if none of above option work, it is possible that your problem is related with lingering ordid issue. What you can do is contact Microsoft Support directly and ask them to route your issue to Windows Azure Support. This is only specific to Windows Azure Portal login issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new account with an other email address. You can have a free trial per email address.